# Playing a wav file in Java after compiling it to JAR

Tags: java, audio, intellij-idea, jar, wav

so I am making a birthday present for a programmer friend of mine. I am not that good with code but I made a window + gif + sound. But once I test it on another PC the sound won't work anymore, but the JAR file is big enough to contain the WAV. PLease help me, I really want to make a nice birthday gift. Here is the Sound code + main

```
 public static void play() {
    try {

        File file = new File("C:/Users/timma/IdeaProjects/BirthdayAshley/1" + ".wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame jf = new JFrame ("Happy Birthday");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(617,345);
    jf.add(new Birthday());
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setResizable(false);
    play();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the WAV is inside a JAR, it can't be referenced via a file.
But you can open it via [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). Everything else should stay the same.

```
InputStream stream =
    SomeClassInTheSameJar.class.getResourceAsStream("/BirthdayAshley/1.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<MyClass>.class().getAsStream("/1.wav")` to load the file. So it will loaded from your jar not with an absolut Path that not exists.

```
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(<MyClass>.class.getAsStream("/1.wav")));
```